# SEO url file name to pretty url

Tags: wordpress, url, seo

If a aged ranked page in Google is something like http://website.com/fun.html
and I change it to http://www.website/fun will this affect the rank or previous juice?
I ask because we are rebuilding a site for a client that has been around for many years
with hundreds of pages with urls like that. Basically its taking of the .html

Also we have a link like http://website.com/books.html I'm assuming
if we change it to http://website.com/services/books.html it will completely
destroy the SEO, am I right?

Ps the new site is a wordpress.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Yes, it will affect their rankings as it is a new url which the search engines consider a new page. You need to do 301 redirects from the old url to the new url so the search engines can associate the new url and old url and preserve their rankings.

Comment: Makes sense. Appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer is: Yes. Google looks at `fun.html` and `/fun/` as 2 separate pages. To associate the two pages you will need to add a 301 redirect from `fun.html` to `fun` either in your WordPress roots `.htaccess` file or you can [install a plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=301+Redirects) to take care of it for you.